# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jaxb

I am very new to hibernate. I was trying to make my first app with hibernate and got next exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.
>
> **NoClassDefFoundError:**
>   javax/xml/bind/JAXBException  at
>   org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader$1.initialize(ConfigLoader.java:41)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader$1.initialize(ConfigLoader.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.util.ValueHolder.getValue(ValueHolder.java:55)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:152)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:19) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
>     ... 7 more

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>app</groupId>
    <artifactId>qapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

main method

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   SessionFactory sessionFactory;
   StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry =
            new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
   Metadata metadata =
            new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry)
            .getMetadataBuilder().build();
        sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
}
```

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j

Answer (score 5):

You are missing dependencies. For your specific case, it is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You may see other issues like this (`NoClassDefFoundError`), check your dependencies and add the related dependency if it is missing.

Comment: This worked for me. It seems javax.xml.bind module is deprecated in Java 9 so needs to be included manually.